# Show that the orbits are given by ellipses $\omega^{2}x^{2}+v^{2}=C$, where $C$ is any non- negative constant.

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, physics, nonlinear-system

I am working through a text book by [Strogatz Nonlinear dynamics and chaos](http://www.hds.bme.hu/%7Efhegedus/Strogatz%20-%20Nonlinear%20Dynamics%20and%20Chaos.pdf) . In chapter 5 question 5.1.1 (a). I have answered the question but would like to check if I have performed the integration step properly.

#### Question

**Show that the orbits are given by ellipses $\omega^{2}x^{2}+v^{2}=C$, where $C$ is any non- negative constant.**

#### Answer

Starting with dividing one equation with the other:
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow  \frac{\dot{x}}{\dot{v}} = \frac{v}{- \omega^{2} x} \\
 -\omega^{2} x  \dot{x} = v \dot{v}
\\ \omega^{2} x  \dot{x} + v \dot{v} = 0 \text{.}
\end{equation}

Then integrating (The integral of 0 is constant D):
\begin{equation}
\int \omega^{2} x \dot{x} \text{ }dx + \int v \dot{v} \text{ }dv = \int 0 \text{ } dx \\
\frac{1}{2} \omega^{2} x^{2} + \frac{1}{2} v^{2}  = D \\
\omega^{2} x^{2} +  v^{2}  = 2 D \\
\omega^{2} x^{2} +  v^{2}  = C
\end{equation}

#### Summary

Could someone please verify this proof, particularly with regards to the $\int \omega^{2} x \dot{x} \text{ }dx + \int v \dot{v} \text{ }dv = \int 0 \text{ } dx $ line. Did I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivatives (with a point above) are with respect to the variable time $ t .$

So, when you integrate, you should do it according to $t$.

$$\int \omega^2xx'dt+\int vv'dt=\int 0dt$$

Comment: Thank you @hamam_Abdallah this helps a lot hahaha